# Using VBS to sort column in excel while maintaining expanded selection

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a csv file that gets created and I want to sort a column but have it expand the selection otherwise the data is not accurate. Example: Column A is the server names, Column B is installed Hotfix Date, column C is who it was installed by.

When using the following code it sort column B for installed date but does not keep that date that was in the other columns with it.

```
      Const xlAscending = 1 
Const xlDescending = 2 
Const xlYes = 1 

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\users\x\desktop\hotfixes.csv") 'insert link or URL to sharepoint document.


Set objRange = objworkbook.worksheets(1).columns(2) 
objRange.Sort objrange.cells(1,1), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes 





objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 
objworkbook.save 
objworkbook.close 
objexcel.quit
```

I have attached a link to sample csv file that I work with. Does anyone know what command I need to enter to keep the whole selection.

https://static.spiceworks.com/attachments/post/0017/4443/hotfixes.txt

Answer (score 1):

It's doing exactly what you told it to do - it's sorting Column 2. It's working just the same as if you opened the file, manually highlighted a single column then hit one of the quick sort buttons - it's sorting that highlighted range ONLY.

Try something like:

```
With objworkbook.worksheets(1)
    Set objRange = .range(.columns(1),.columns(3))
    objrange.sort objrange.cells(1,2), xlascending, , , , , , xlYes 
End With
```

This expands your sort range to include columns 1 - 3, then keys it to sort on the second column. It should resolve your issue.